# Questions from a new git user

Tags: git

I've been using centralized repositories until now but recently at work I've been moved onto a project using git. I read through the tutorial and had some noob questions.

From my understanding:

```
Step 1: git init --bare or create a remote repo (github/stash/etc.)
Step 2: git clone <repo URL/PATH>
Step 3: git checkout -b <new_branch> master
Step 4: git add <file/dir>
Step 5: git commit -m <msg>
Step 6: Repeat steps 4 and 5 until new feature is done
Step 7: git rebase -i master
Step 8: pick/reword/squash until satisified

local master branch
Step 9: git checkout <base_branch>
Step 10: git merge

remote repo
Step 9: pull request from new branch to master
Step 10: get approval from repo owner
```

Please correct me if I have the flow wrong.

What I'm confused about is, at work we use Stash. My colleague cloned from the remote repo using the generated URL.

My colleague gave me the URL he used so I cloned his repo.

1. How do I do the pull request? How do I select my branch to the master?
2. How do I git remote such that my origin becomes the remote repo instead of my colleagues repo?

Comment: I think it's better to read some tutorials first, like Pro Git.

Comment: Please edit your title to say what your question actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Simply to speak, After you have initialized a git repo in your local 
You first need to add the link to the original url
i.e `git remote add origin "Remote repo link"`.
You can check to see if the source link has been added by entering `git remote -v`.
Pulling from the source is as simple as `git pull origin master`

Answer (score 0):

1. Stash is now bit bucket server, but pull requests should be similar through [their gui](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request/).
2. You change the url for a remote with `set-url`

   ```
   git remote set-url origin git@example.com: username/yourrepo.git
   ```